# Magento Commerce Cloud : Tool for real time monitoring of sql queries and processes

Tags: database, performance, magento2-cloud, profiler, benchmark

I need to monitor the number of SQL queries and processes and their corresponding CPU and swap usages in real-time just like the monitoring tool provided with PHPMyAdmin. I need something similar for commerce cloud environment.

Please note that I have already used Newrelic APM and it seems it only provides historical data. Also, `show processlist` command on mysql-cli does not auto-refresh so that does not fulfill the requirement as well.

Comment: Look into grafana. Although I don't know whether you can implement that on commerce cloud.

Comment: Have you tried PHPAdmin with your cloud instance?  Who is your hosting company?

Comment: PHPAdmin not very secure and hence not recommended on production systems.

Comment: Also, the commerce cloud is hosted by Magento.

Comment: What is Magento's suggested alternative to PHPAdmin?

Comment: Consider jetprofiler.com if you can get access to OS CLI.  Nothing is done to MySQL for this realtime monitoring tool and you will see Top Queries, Tables and Schemas.  Top Queries can be 'explained' with this software - for LX, Mac or Windows.

Comment: @VivekKumar Have you had an opportunity to try JetProfiler.com?  Your thoughts?